# Why is my react state not being updated?

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code.

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4> {this.props.title} </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Root = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var title = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).value.trim();
       console.log(title)
       this.setState({title: title})
    },
    render: function() {
      return(
        <div>
            <Child title="Sample Fruit"/>
            <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="New Title..." ref="title" />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

React.render(<Root />, document.body);
```

The value of `this.props.title` is not getting updated and it is re-rendering the same old title value `Sample Fruit`. What am I missing?

I honestly think that this is enough of a description for the problem I'm facing, but StackOverflow is asking me to add more text. So here it goes.

Comment: You pass the constant `"Sample Fruit"` value, why should it render something else?

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you for pointing that out! I feel so dumb.